# How to root View Controller in App Delegate extension?

Tags: ios, swift

### The issue of Navigation Push And Pop animated Off When Change Root View Controller in appDelegate

If I do this write below code it's working, but my every viewController push, present, and pop animated off.
How to use AppDelegate use window object?

### AppDelegate extension

```
extension AppDelegate {
func PresentLoginNavigationControllerScreen()-> Void {
    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

func PresentHomeNavigationControllerScreen()-> Void
{
    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeNavigationController")
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
}
```

### HomeViewController

```
@IBAction func LogoutButtonOnClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate! as? AppDelegate
        {
           appDelegate.PresentLoginNavigationControllerScreen()
        }
}
```

If I change `logout` button click `appdelegate` function called and change to `HomeViewController` To `LoginViewController` then Navigation pushing animated to going disable. My any screen not animating. But i will application close to again Open Then animted working.

> Please tell me How to change root view controller in appDelegate and Relaunch App.

Comment: Changing the root view controller doesn't have default animation to it.

Comment: And you can't relaunch the app.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to change the rootViewController rather than using the `present(_:animated:completion:)` method?

Comment: Making an `extension` of `AppDelegate` is quite useless because `AppDelegate` is only one. So better to define functions in your `AppDelegate` class.

Comment: You don't need to call `self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` line  just change the `rootViewController` and don't forget to assign `navigationController` to make the push functional.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch `rootViewController` in transition block like this.

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.window, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {            
    self.window.rootViewController = newViewController
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in
    //Completion process
})
```

Hope this will help you.